# How to start a webserver in a package that doesn't block main program

Tags: go

I am trying to create a package for Golang that starts a webserver to view output of the importing program in the browser.

However, the webserver only starts if I call the package RunServer function within a goroutine, but if I call the package RunServer function in a go routine, then my importing program is not finishing, so I must be doing something wrong.

My package has this code

```
func RunServer(){

h := NewMux()
h.registerHandlers()
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8001", h.mux)
}

func (h *HandleServer) registerHandlers(){
 h.mux.HandleFunc("/", h.rootHandler)
}
func(h *HandleServer) rootHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
 fmt.Fprintf(w, "root handler")
}
```

And, in an attempt to figure out the problem, my importing program does both of these.

First Case:

```
go func(){
  mypackage.RunServer()
}
```

Second Case (no go routine):

```
 mypackage.RunServer()
```

In the second case, the webserver in my package starts, and I can read the rootHandler output in the browser without any warnings, but my program that imports the package doesn't finish running.

In the first case, the importing program runs to completion, but when I check the browser, it says "local host refused to connect/ site cannot be reached etc"

How can I make the importing program run to completion and have the webserver in the package run as well.

Note, the importing program doesn't start a webserver on its own.

Update: Somebody in the comments asked for a reproducible example. You just have to comment out the relevant code in the startLibraryServer function
[Link to reproducible example-2 files](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/3v7s4qtqdutn4vkxipit3/h?rlkey=yjyxv01pw6t0251iaaxvxrz38&dl=0)

Comment: „ How can I make the importing program run to completion and have the webserver in the package run as well.“ you cannot.

Comment: @Volker Can you please explain why I cannot? What is the technical explanation for it. I thought/hoped it might be possible (but didn't know how to do it) to start the imported packages webserver as a background process that didn't close when the main program ran to completion.

Comment: The „technical explanation“ you ask for is a plain „you simply cannot do this“. When main returns the program stops (including your webserver) and there is nothing you can do about this. Redesign.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] showing what program is not finishing? Please put this inline into the Q as per site guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use channels to make the program wait until your signal:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "os/signal"

)

func main() {
    makeGraph()
}

func makeGraph() {
    startlibraryServer()
    MainProgram()

    // Wait for interrupt signal to gracefully shutdown the server 
    // Use a buffered channel to avoid missing signals as recommended for signal.Notify
    quit := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(quit, os.Interrupt)
    <-quit
}
func startlibraryServer() {

    //desired result: to start the webserver in the package and keep it running even after MainProgram finishes.

    go func() {

      library_server.RunGD()
    }()

}

const N = 10000000

(... continue your program)
```